# Parent Class, Extends Ext.form.Panel, Add DockedItmes

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've got a parent class `ParentPanel` that extends `Ext.form.Panel` in Ext JS 5. The parent panel is roughly defined as follows:

```
Ext.define('...ParentPanel', {

    config : {  
        isItTrue : true
    },  

    dockedItems: [],

    initComponent : function () {  
        var me = this; 

        //If some evaluation is true...  
        if (isItTrue) {
            me.dockedItems.push({  
                // the components I am trying to add...  
            });  

        this.callParent():
    }

    //....
```

The basic problem is that any class extending `ParentPanel` will call the `initComponent` function, adding the items to the *parent* `dockedItems` config. for every `true` evaluation (so I end up with repetitions as each child is sharing the parent's `dockedItems` config.). What I *want* to do is to only have the item added to the inheriting classes `dockedItems` configuration, not the parent.

Is this even possible is Ext JS? If so, understanding the design issue, how would I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
initComponent: function () {  
    this.dockedItems = [];
    // ...
}
```

ExtJS doesn't change the nature of Javascript...

Comment: So, don't maintain a global reference to `dockedItems` in the parent, then? Just "add" the docked items to the calling child through `initComponent`? (Just making sure I understand)

Comment: I like the design decision. Way better than what I was about to propose: each child has a `dockedItems` config. that is defaulted to `[]`, i.e. maintains it's own "local" reference to a `dockedItems` config.

Comment: Ext surely does not expect you to have references (array, objects...) shared between multiple instances. It will itself modify them (for example, it will replace all config object by actual instances in `items`, etc.). You'll get weird and hard to debug behaviours if you do that.